# How to change button text of RecyclerView Item in Fragment A from a different Fragment B

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I have two fragments, **Fragment A** **Fragment B**, in one single activity. In the fragment A, I have implemented the **RecyclerView**, which shows a list of items, each item - as a TextView's text with the ViewHolder's help.
What I want - is to change the background colour of TextView in RecyclerView by clicking a Button in **Fragment B**

I've attached picture:

[Image of both of fragments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jPL1u.png)

Here is code of **Main Activity**

```
package com.tutorials180.changerecycleritem;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction;

import android.os.Bundle;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    FragOne objectFragOne=new FragOne();
    FragTwo objectFragTwo=new FragTwo();
    public MyAdapter.MyInterfaceJIP objectMyInterfaceJIP;
    ArrayList<String> arrayList;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        arrayList=new ArrayList<>();
        arrayList.add("Hi");
        arrayList.add("Bi");
        arrayList.add("new");
        changeFragment(objectFragOne,arrayList);

    }

    public void changeFragment(Fragment object, MyAdapter.MyInterfaceJIP objectMyInterfaceJIP)
    {
        Bundle bearTokenBundle=new Bundle();
        bearTokenBundle.putParcelable("interface",objectMyInterfaceJIP);
        bearTokenBundle.putStringArrayList("my",arrayList);

        object.setArguments(bearTokenBundle);
        FragmentTransaction objectFragmentTransaction=getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        objectFragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container,object).commit();
    }

    public void changeFragment(Fragment object,ArrayList<String> data)
    {
        Bundle bearTokenBundle=new Bundle();
        bearTokenBundle.putStringArrayList("my",data);

        object.setArguments(bearTokenBundle);
        FragmentTransaction objectFragmentTransaction=getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        objectFragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container,object).commit();
    }
}
```

Code Of Adapter

```
 package com.tutorials180.changerecycleritem;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder>{

    FragOne objectFragOne;
    FragTwo objectFragTwo;

    Context context;

    ArrayList<String> objArrayList;

    public MyAdapter(FragOne objectFragOne, FragTwo objectFragTwo, Context context, ArrayList<String> objArrayList) {
        this.objectFragOne = objectFragOne;
        this.objectFragTwo = objectFragTwo;
        this.context = context;
        this.objArrayList = objArrayList;
    }

    public interface MyInterfaceJIP extends Parcelable {
        public void deleteItem();
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new MyViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.single_item,parent,false));
    }

    boolean moved=false;
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        if(!moved){
            holder.objectTextView.setText("MOVE");}
        else if(moved)
        {
            holder.objectTextView.setText("Moved Baby");}
        holder.objectTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                final MainActivity obj= (MainActivity)context;
                moved=true;
                obj.changeFragment(objectFragTwo, new MyInterfaceJIP() {
                    @Override
                    public int describeContents() {
                        return 0;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int i) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void deleteItem() {
                        moved=true;
                        obj.changeFragment(objectFragOne,objArrayList);
                        //notifyItemChanged(position);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return objArrayList.size();
    }

    class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {
        TextView objectTextView;
        public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            objectTextView=itemView.findViewById(R.id.sr_text);
        }
    }
}
```

code of Fragment A

```
    package com.tutorials180.changerecycleritem;

import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class FragOne extends Fragment {

    public FragOne() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    View view;
    RecyclerView objectRecyclerView;

    ArrayList<String> object;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_frag_one, container, false);
        objectRecyclerView=view.findViewById(R.id.RV);

        object=new ArrayList<>();
        if(getArguments()!=null)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "INside", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            object=getArguments().getStringArrayList("my");
            MyAdapter objectMyAdapter=new MyAdapter(new FragOne(),new FragTwo(),getContext(),object);
            objectRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));

            objectRecyclerView.setAdapter(objectMyAdapter);
            objectRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

            objectMyAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }


        return view;
    }
}
```

Fragment Two

```
    package com.tutorials180.changerecycleritem;

import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class FragTwo extends Fragment {

    public FragTwo() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    public MyAdapter.MyInterfaceJIP objectMyInterfaceJIP;
    View view,view2;

    Button button;
    TextView rvBtn;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_frag_two, container, false);
        view2=inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_item, container, false);
        button=view.findViewById(R.id.btn);
        rvBtn=view2.findViewById(R.id.sr_text);
        if(getArguments()!=null)
        {   objectMyInterfaceJIP=getArguments().getParcelable("interface");

            button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    rvBtn.setBackgroundColor(getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
                    objectMyInterfaceJIP.deleteItem();
                }
            });
        }
        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: User Shared ViewModel https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#sharing

Comment: Not getting any idea from it.

Comment: Found the Solution, declare a variable in parent activity and draw the text view in Recycler View according to that variable values. This might not be the final one but, it is trick, to solve the problem, but if anyone finds a better solution, he/she is more than just welcome to share.

Answer (score 0):

**Found the Solution**, declare a variable in parent activity and draw the text view in Recycler View according to that variable values. This might not be the final solution but it is a kind of trick, to solve the problem, but if anyone finds a better solution, he/she is more than just welcome to share.